# External Javascript is not working after converting html/bootstrap template into react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/lib/wow/wow.min.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/lib/easing/easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/lib/waypoints/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/lib/tempusdominus/js/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I copied my assets folder in the public folder of the React project and put all reference tags accordingly in the head section and in the body section but when the application loads everything is working except Javascript (animation, some scroll functions are not working) some of my js working some of it is not, anyone with the same problem or anyone who solved it, I've tried everything but got no luck, please help me if you can.

Comment: Have you tried to add the following statements into to src/index.js

import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

Comment: tried, but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Most of the JavaScript libraries you've included won't work in a React application. You either need to find React friendly alternatives to those, or create special wrappers. This happens because methods like `document.querySelector` will not work out of the box in a React application, because you either need to wrap them in a `useEffect` hook to make sure your DOM is loaded, or use `useRef` instead.

Comment: brother can you provide me some code example cause i tried and got error and don't know where im wrong or making mistake and im beginner :( Thanks

Comment: @MahadAhmad There is no code. Please read the first sentence. Bootstrap JS doesn't work with React. You have to code your own alternative or find a React-friendly alternative.